# Vue 3 display fetch data v-for

Tags: vue.js, fetch, vuejs3

So, I'm creating a Pokemon application and I would like to display the pokemon names using the api : https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/.
I'm doing a fetch request on the api and then display the pokemon names in my template. I have 0 problem when I try to display only 1 pokemon but I have this error when I try to display all my pokemons using v-for.
Do you have any idea why I meet this error ?[image]

```html
<template>
    <p class="dark:text-white"> {{pokemons[0].name}} </p> //working
    <div v-for="(pokemon, index) in pokemons" :key="'poke'+index"> //not working...
        {{ pokemon.name }} 
    </div>
</template>

<script>
const apiURL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            nextURL:"",
            pokemons: [],
        };
    },
    created(){
        this.fetchPokemons();
    },
    methods:{
        fetchPokemons(){
            fetch(apiURL)
            .then( (resp) => {
                if(resp.status === 200){
                    return resp.json();
                }
            })
            .then( (data) => {
                console.log(data.results)
                // data.results.forEach(pokemon => {
                //     this.pokemons.push(pokemon)
                // });
                // this.nextURL = data.next;
                this.pokemons = data.results;
                console.log(this.pokemons);
            })
            .catch( (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just pasted your code into a Code Pen and removed the working/not working comments and the code runs and shows the names.

Maybe the problem is in the parent component where this component is mounted, or the assignment of the :key attribute
try `:key="'poke'+index.toString()"`, but I'm pretty sure js handels string integer concats quiet well.

Which version of vuejs do you use?

**Edit from comments:**

The parent component with the name `PokemonListVue` imported the posted component as `PokemonListVue` which resulted in a naming conflict. Renaming either one of those solves the issue.

In the error message posted, in line 3 it says `at formatComponentName` this is a good hint.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'm really suprised my code works on codepen. I should have tried that. 

My version of vue is : "vue": "^3.2.13"

I tried to had .toString() but not worked..

Comment: Do you mount your component or is the code you posted your root component (app.vue)?
Maybe you can share the code where the component you've posted is used.

Comment: I've tried your code in seperate project and it works too, I think there is no problem with the component itself.
BTW: ^ in package.json means at least version 3.2.13 to see which version is actually installed look into the package-lock.json. But ether way I've tried 3.2.13 and 3.2.25 and the code works

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your answers. I don't really understand what is happening if the code is working on your computer..

So, My code is a component that I include in a view like this :

`<template>
  <PokemonListVue></PokemonListVue>
</template>

<script>
import PokemonListVue from "@/components/PokemonList.vue";
export default{
    name: PokemonListVue,
    components: {
        PokemonListVue
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>`

Comment: okay, based on your comment you're importing the component named PokemonListVue from PokemonList and the componend where you import and use it has the name specified PokemonListVue that might be a conflict. Try renaming either one

Comment: I answered to your last comment some minutes after but I can't find my comment. Again, it worked, sorry for the trouble and thank you very much for your time and your answers. You helped me alot